# Jhipster Authority will effect only on a system restart

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

Jhipster Authority will effect only on a system restart. How to reset authority cache when modified a specific users authorities?

Answer (score 1):

Not only after a restart, cache entries are evicted based on `time-to-live-seconds` property in `application*.yml` configuration too.

Anyway you can clear the cache as in  `UserService.clearUserCaches()` whenever you want.